# Binary (de)serialization in c++

Tags: c++, serialization

I'm trying to make a simple library for de/serialization in c++, but I know it can be tricky to implement, so I'd really like to have my code reviewed to see if there's anything that stands out and/or can be improved. [Here](https://gitlab.com/Nitr4m12/simple-binaryio) is the full repo containing all the code. Any other necessary code can be found there, as most of it was written by others.

**binaryio/reader.h**:

```
#include <memory>
#include <span>
#include <stdexcept>

#include "binaryio/interface.h"
#include "binaryio/swap.h"

#ifndef BINARYIO_READER_H
#define BINARYIO_READER_H

namespace binaryio {

class BinaryReader : IBinaryIO {
public:
    BinaryReader(void* const begin, void* const end)
        : m_begin(reinterpret_cast<char*>(begin)),
          m_end(reinterpret_cast<char*>(end)),
          m_current(reinterpret_cast<char*>(begin)){};

    BinaryReader(void* const begin, void* const end, const endian& endianness)
        : m_begin{reinterpret_cast<char*>(begin)},
          m_end{reinterpret_cast<char*>(end)},
          m_current{reinterpret_cast<char*>(begin)}, m_endian{endianness} {};

    BinaryReader(void* const begin, const std::ptrdiff_t& size)
        : m_begin{reinterpret_cast<char*>(begin)}, m_end{m_begin + size},
          m_current{reinterpret_cast<char*>(begin)} {};

    BinaryReader(void* const begin, const std::ptrdiff_t& size,
                 const endian& endianness)
        : m_begin{reinterpret_cast<char*>(begin)}, m_end{m_begin + size},
          m_current{reinterpret_cast<char*>(begin)}, m_endian{endianness} {};

    void seek(std::ptrdiff_t offset) override {
        if (m_begin + offset > m_end)
            throw std::out_of_range("out of bounds seek");

        m_current = m_begin + offset;
    }

    size_t tell() const override {
        size_t offset{static_cast<size_t>(m_current - m_begin)};
        return offset;
    }

    template <typename T>
    T read() {
        if (m_current + sizeof(T) > m_end)
            throw std::out_of_range("out of bounds read");

        T val = *(T*)m_current;
        swap_if_needed_in_place(val, m_endian);
        m_current += sizeof(T);
        return val;
    }

    std::string read_string(size_t max_len = 0) {
        if (m_current + max_len > m_end || max_len == 0)
            max_len = m_end - m_current;

        return {m_current, strnlen(m_current, max_len)};
    }

    template <typename T>
    std::span<T> read_many(int count) {
        if (m_current + sizeof(T) * count > m_end)
            throw std::out_of_range("out of bound read");

        std::span<T> vals{{}, count};
        for (int i{0}; i < count; ++i) {
            vals[i] = *(T*)m_current;
            swap_if_needed_in_place(vals[i], m_endian);
            m_current += sizeof(T);
        }
        return vals;
    }

    endian endianness() { return m_endian; }

    void set_endianness(endian new_endian) { m_endian = new_endian; }

    void swap_endianness() {
        if (m_endian == endian::big)
            m_endian = endian::little;
        else
            m_endian = endian::big;
    }

private:
    char* m_begin;
    char* m_end;
    char* m_current;
    endian m_endian{endian::native};
};
} // namespace binaryio
#endif
```

**binaryio/writer.h**:

```
#include <memory>
#include <span>
#include <vector>

#include "binaryio/align.h"
#include "binaryio/interface.h"
#include "binaryio/swap.h"

#ifndef BINARYIO_WRITER_H
#define BINARYIO_WRITER_H

namespace binaryio {
class BinaryWriter : IBinaryIO {
public:
    // Based on
    // https://github.com/zeldamods/oead/blob/master/src/include/oead/util/binary_reader.h
    BinaryWriter() = default;

    BinaryWriter(endian byte_order) : m_endian{byte_order} {};

    std::vector<uint8_t> finalize() { return std::move(m_storage); }

    void seek(std::ptrdiff_t offset) override { m_offset = offset; };
    size_t tell() const override { return m_offset; }

    void write_bytes(const uint8_t* data, size_t size) {
        std::span<const uint8_t> bytes{data, size};

        if (m_offset + bytes.size() > m_storage.size())
            m_storage.resize(m_offset + bytes.size());

        std::memcpy(&m_storage[m_offset], bytes.data(), bytes.size());
        m_offset += bytes.size();
    };

    template <typename T,
              typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_pointer_v<T> &&
                                        std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T>>* = nullptr>
    void write(T value) {
        swap_if_needed_in_place(value, m_endian);
        write_bytes(reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(&value), sizeof(value));
    }

    void write(std::string_view str) {
        write_bytes(reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(str.data()), str.size());
    }

    void write_null() { write<uint8_t>(0); }

    void write_cstr(std::string_view str) {
        write(str);
        write_null();
    }

    void align_up(size_t n) { seek(AlignUp(tell(), n)); }

private:
    std::vector<uint8_t> m_storage;
    size_t m_offset{0};
    endian m_endian{endian::native};
};
} // namespace binaryio

#endif
```

And here's a test I wrote using a **wav** file as a base:

````
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>

#include "binaryio/reader.h"
#include "binaryio/writer.h"

struct FileHeader {
    uint32_t magic;
    uint32_t fileSize;
    BINARYIO_DEFINE_FIELDS(FileHeader, magic, fileSize);
};

struct WaveFile {
    FileHeader riffHeader;
    std::array<uint8_t, 4> magic;
    std::array<uint8_t, 4> fmt;
    uint32_t fmtSize;
    uint16_t audioFormat;
    uint16_t numChannels;
    uint32_t sampleRate;
    uint32_t byteRate;
    uint16_t blockAlign;
    uint16_t bitsPerSample;
    std::array<uint8_t, 4> dataMagic;
    uint32_t dataSize;
    // Data starts
    BINARYIO_DEFINE_FIELDS(WaveFile, riffHeader, magic, fmt, fmtSize, audioFormat, numChannels, sampleRate, byteRate, blockAlign, bitsPerSample, dataMagic, dataSize);
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
try {
    std::vector<uint8_t> bytes(std::filesystem::file_size(argv[1]));
    {
        std::ifstream ifs{argv[1]};
        ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(bytes.data()), bytes.size());
    }

    // Read from the byte buffer
    binaryio::BinaryReader reader{bytes.begin().base(), bytes.end().base()};
    WaveFile wav {reader.read<WaveFile>()};
    std::vector<uint8_t> data;
    for (int i {sizeof(WaveFile)}; i<bytes.size(); ++i)
        data.push_back(reader.read<uint8_t>());

    std::cout << "Riff Magic: " << std::hex << wav.riffHeader.magic << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Wave Magic: " << wav.magic.data() << std::endl;

    // Write a new file
    binaryio::BinaryWriter writer{binaryio::endian::little};
    writer.write(wav);
    for (uint8_t byte : data)
        writer.write(byte);

    bytes.clear();
    bytes = writer.finalize();
    {
        std::ofstream ofs{"out_little.wav"};
        ofs.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(bytes.data()), bytes.size());
    }

    // Write a different file with its endianness swapped
    writer = {binaryio::endian::big};
    writer.write(wav);
    for (uint8_t byte : data)
        writer.write(byte);

    bytes.clear();
    bytes = writer.finalize();
    {
        std::ofstream ofs{"out_big.wav"};
        ofs.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(bytes.data()), wav.riffHeader.fileSize + sizeof(FileHeader));
    }

    // Read the new file, and compare the result with the original struct
    reader = {bytes.begin().base(), bytes.end().base()};
    if (reader.read<uint32_t>() == 0x52494646) {
        reader.swap_endianness();
        reader.seek(0);
    }
    WaveFile other_wav {reader.read<WaveFile>()};

    std::cout << "Riff Magic: " << std::hex << other_wav.riffHeader.magic << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Wave Magic: " << other_wav.magic.data() << std::endl;

    if (wav.sampleRate == other_wav.sampleRate)
        std::cout << "Data preserved, endianness swapped" << std::endl;
    else {
        throw std::runtime_error("Something went wrong and the data was changed");
    }

    return 0;
}
catch (std::runtime_error& err) {
    std::cerr << err.what() << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```
````

Comment: I don't understand this code at all. And I don't want the author to tell me, I want the _code_ to tell me. Here's what I'm grappling with. We serialize int64's to a file on host A. We read them back on host B. Where did we write out a Magic Number file prefix? (I think we didn't.) Where did we write out "A was using big-endian, and the file does, too!"? (I think we didn't.) Where does B notice it needs byte swaps to convert to B's little-endian setup? Also, get_platform_endianness() seems to have no notion of A writing data once that will be convenient for B to read a million times. Unit test?

Comment: I'm guessing `swap_if_needed_in_place()` is significant, yet that's not even declared here.  I think we need more of the code to give it a decent review.  And as J_H says, show the unit-tests to give us an idea of intended usage.

Comment: @Nitram The comments say your code is based on code from another project. I checked and that project is licensed under the GPL version 2 or later. You are allowed to reuse that code, but you have to make sure your code also is published under the same license, and regardless, you should credit the original author of the code.

Comment: @G.Sliepen I've licensed it under it GPL version 3. Does that not work? Also, should credits be more visible? I assumed it was enough with the copyright notice of each file detailing where they're from, but I'll add them to the README if that's preferable.

Comment: @Nitram Yes, credits should be visible. The exact details are in the text of the GPL license itself. There might also be a requirement from copyright law, although that varies by jurisdiction of course, and I am not a lawyer. Also have a look at [this post](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/4582). Also note that just adding a link is not enough, and is problematic; websites might move or go offline.

Comment: We can only review the code you have written, and stack exchanged uses a different license. Just post the code you wrote and indicate that the other necessary code is in the repository and was written by others. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Aha! Thank you kindly for that WAV reader. I see now that magic and endian advice happens before the (de)serializer code gets involved. Makes sense. Also, the support for a sequence of varying size fields is lovely.

Comment: Are you familiar with https://stackoverflow.com/q/19103244/313768 ?

Comment: Why is `BinaryReader` not inheriting from `std::istream` and `BinaryWriter` not inheriting from `std::ostream` so I can simply write objects to a Binary stream like I can write objects to any other type of stream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Make the (de)serializer work on streams

If I look at your example `main()`, I see a lot of inefficiencies. Part of that is caused by having to read the data into a memory buffer before it can be deserialized, and similarly you have to completely fill a memory buffer before you can finalize the results and write it out. It would be much nicer if your code could work on files directly. Consider being able to write:

```
std::ifstream ifs{argv[1]};
binaryio::BinaryReader reader{ifs};
auto wav = reader.read<WaveFile>();
…
```

This could be implemented like so:

```
class BinaryReader {
    std::istream& ifs;

public:
    BinaryReader(std::ifstream& ifs): ifs{ifs} {}

    template<typename T>
    T read() {
        T val;

        if (!ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&val), sizeof val))
            throw std::out_of_range("out of bounds read");

        swap_if_needed_in_place(val, m_endian);
        return val;
    }
    …
};
```

Now you might think: but what if my data is not in a file to begin with? The great thing about C++'s I/O functions is that they support more than just files. For example, the above reader can also work on [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream)s, and C++23 makes it easy to turn any contiguous buffer of memory into a stream using [`std::ispanstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ispanstream).

Note that if your classes work on streams, it is no longer necessary to provide stream-like functions like `tell()` and `seek()` yourself.

The same goes for output.

## Make it easy to read and write arrays

Your example shows reading the data from a WAV file byte by byte. That's potentially going to be slow, and it is inconvenient. It would be much nicer if you could write:

```
auto data = reader.read<std::vector<uint8_t>>(wav.datasize);
```

You can make this work by creating an overload for `read()` that checks if `T` is a container (in C++20, that is easy using [concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) like [`std::ranges::output_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/output_range)), and then creates a value of that type and read directly into it.

It might be some work to get it to work for all container types though, and you could instead consider creating a function that only returns `std::vector`s, or a function that takes a `std::span` to read into, so that you can write code like:

```
auto data = reader.read_vector<uint8_t>(wav.datasize);
// or:
std::vector<uint8_t> data(wav.datasize);
reader.read_span(std::span{data});
```

## About endianness

If you call `reader.read<WaveFile>()`, how does your code know how to swap endianness? Not everything is a 32-bit value in the WAV header, and the WAV data might contain samples in various formats, not just 8 bit values. If you swap 32 bits at a time, then two consecutive 16-bit fields in the header might get swapped. If your data consists of 8-bit samples, they should never be swapped.

Most serialization libraries allow you to provide custom serializers for your own types. That way, you can provide a serializer for `WaveFile` that serializes each header value separately. There are several approaches possible. For example, you could allow user code to overload the read and write functions, or you could check if a given type has `serialize()` and `deserialize()` member functions. Have a look at how [Boost Serialization](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html) handles this.

Comment: The way it deals with endianness is with the `BINARYIO_DEFINE_FIELDS` macro, which exposes every field passed to it so that it can automatically check the size and and swap accordingly.

Comment: I don't see a definition of that macro, nor of `swap_if_needed_in_place()`, so I had to guess.

Comment: I just wanted to say thanks for the feedback. Refactoring it to use streams instead makes the code much more streamlined, although I can't test it with `std::spanstream` since C++23 doesn't seem to be available yet (please correct me if I'm wrong). I also would like to point out that reading straight into the vector data was about 2x faster that what I was doing before.

Comment: Found out that I just had to update on my end, so please ignore that part about C++23 not being available.

Comment: No problem! It's good to hear that my suggestions improved your code. Consider posting the refactored code as a new question on Code Review. It would also be interesting to see how you implemented BINARYIO_DEFINE_FIELDS and `swap_if_needed_in_place()`.

Answer (score 2):

### BinaryReader

constructors:

- I think the constructors should take `char*`s, not `void*`s to be clear to the user what's actually needed (a contiguous array of characters). Any necessary `reinterpret_cast`ing should be done by the user, where it's nice and visible.
- Why does a "Reader" class take a mutable range? We should probably be taking a `const char*` (or `char const*`).
- Use `std::size_t`, not `std::ptrdiff_t`, since we expect a contiguous range, and `begin` should always be before `end` (we should probably check that). Pass it by value, not `const&`.
- Assuming `endian` is an enum, it should also be passed by value.

`seek()` / `tell()`:

- The range check in seek is inadequate; since `std::ptrdiff_t` can be negative we may end up before `m_begin`, as well as after `m_end`.
- In C++ we should use `std::size_t` instead of `size_t`, as the latter is technically not guaranteed to be present.

`read()`:

- C-style casting should be avoided, because it's ambiguous and dangerous.
- We also need to be careful about C++'s "strict aliasing" rules. We can examine the underlying representation of a `T` by casting a `T*` to a `char*`, but there's no guarantee that the opposite will work. To convert our array of chars to a `T`, we need to use [`std::memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy), bearing in mind that `T` must be trivially copyable. So:

```
    T val;
    std::memcpy(&val, m_current, sizeof(T));
```

- `BinaryWriter::write()` checks that the object type is trivially copyable - we should do that here too.

`read_string()`:

- As a user, I'd expect that setting `max_len` to zero would return an empty string. Consider setting `std::string::npos` as the default value for `max_len`, and use it to symbolize taking the maximum possible string, similar to how [`std::string::substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) behaves.

`read_many()`:

- Should take a `std::size_t`, not an `int` parameter.
- Could use the existing `read()` function to read the value (or abstract the functionality to a private member function to avoid duplicate bounds checking).

---

### `BinaryWriter`

Using `uint8_t` for the storage type is inconsistent with the `BinaryReader`. It might be simpler to use `char` for both.

`seek()` / `tell()`:

- Your compiler should give you an error message about mismatched types, since `m_offset` is a `size_t`, and `offset` a `std::ptrdiff_t`. If not, turn up your compiler warning level and enable warnings as errors!
- The offset in `seek` is treated as an absolute value, rather than a relative value which is how it's treated in `BinaryReader`. This inconsistency is confusing and potentially dangerous. If we do want to use an absolute value, `std::size_t` would be a better choice than `std::ptrdiff_t`. (As is, we need to check somewhere that `m_offset` isn't negative).

`write_bytes()`:

- Why not just take the `span` as the parameter?
- The C++ version of `uint8_t` is `std::uint8_t`. However, I think we actually need a `char*` or `unsigned char*` instead. `std::uint8_t` is usually (almost certainly) a typedef for `unsigned char`, but it may technically be something else. If it isn't `unsigned char` then we run into "strict aliasing" problems again. We can only get the object representation by casting to `char*`, `unsigned char*`, or `std::byte`. So we should be taking one of those three types as a parameter to this function.

  We're already using `std::memcpy` to go from the object representation to storage, which is good!
- We're missing an equivalent `read_bytes` on the `BinaryReader`.

`write()`:

- See above about accessing the underlying object representation.
- `write(string_view)` `write_null`, `write_cstr` and `align_up` are all oddly specific for a general purpose binary writer. Perhaps they'd be better placed with the relevant reading / writing code for the specific file formats that need them?

Comment: Could you clarify why should some things be passed by value? I assumed it would be more memory efficient to pass by (const) reference in most cases

Comment: On a 64 bit system, a std::ptrdiff_t will usually be 64 bits. A pointer (or reference) will also be 64 bits and has the additional performance cost of the indirection (although in practice it will probably be optimized to simply pass by value anyway). It's just more readable to pass small built-in types by value, and makes passing by mutable reference stand out more.